# How do you print a std::regex?

Tags: c++, regex, string, printing, cout

How do you print the string representation of a `std::regex`?

Say I have a collection of patterns, and I'd like to print the first one that matches:

```
std::vector<std::regex>> patterns = Get();
for (auto pattern: patterns){
  if (std::regex_match("file.txt",pattern)){
    std::cout << "matched on pattern: " << /* ? pattern ? */ << '\n';
  }
}
```

`std::cout` will not work on `std::regex`.

There doesn't seem to be any methods to get the string representation.

Are we expected to carry around a string separately, or am I missing something in the docs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> There doesn't seem to be any methods to get the string representation.

Correct. It is not even specified that the `std::regex` even saves your expression in the form you gave it, which might be the case if the implementation decides to use some more optimized format.

Comment: Rats.  Seems pretty inconvenient to me, but I guess its not something everyone wants to pay for.  I'll make a wrapper type...

Comment: True, especially since boost::regex can be printed.